# How to make TbModal work properly in PhP (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I am looking to make a simple Pop-Up window using TbModal (as requested by my superiors). However, I have no clue how to do this. I have never written a modal before and I am not certain if I am doing it completely wrong.

All I need to do, is to create a Pop-up window once a button is clicked. In this window I need to simply add a name, a description and something that is called carousel. However, whenever I try to make it work I get the following error:

**Alias "bootstrap.widgets.TbModal" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.**

Below is what the button in my view looks like (using a TbButtonColumn):

```
'buttons'=>array(
        'update'=>array(
        ),
        'delete'=>array(
        ),
        'clone'=>array(
          'id'=>'clone-dashboard-button',
          'label'=>'Clone',
          'title'=>'Clone',
          'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("path/to/actionClone", array("id"=>$data->id))',
          'option'=>array(
            'rel'=>'tooltip',
            'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
            'title'=>'Clone'
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

As well as the modal:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
    'id'=>'clone-form',
    // 'focus'=>'#Dashboard_clone_title',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'tabindex'=>'-1',
    ))); ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h4>Test</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="model-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-md-2">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'title', array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>20,'class'=>'resize-non form-control')); // Title input?>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-md-2">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description', array('rows'=>1, 'cols'=>30,'class'=>'resize-non form-control')); //Description ?>
        </div>
        <div class ="col-md-2">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'carousel'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->checkbox($model,'carousel'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <!--Buttons-->
    <div class="pull-right">
      <?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType'=>'Clone',
        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("path/to/actionClone", array("id"=>$data->id))',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
          'onClick'=>"
          $(this).attr(\"disabled\", \"disabled\");"
        ),
      )); ?>
      <?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType'=>'button',
        'label'=>'Cancel',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
          'data-dismiss'=>'modal',
        ),
      )); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```